# How make "submit" form work from Ajax after push on button

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, forms, submit

I have form and need use Ajax. All ok when I sent email after push "enter" on keyboard. When I want use "button" in HTML it is does not work.
I try use "click"  for my button in my JS file but it refresh page and I just get message(customise message) on empty page.

```
 <form action="{{ route('odh.giftcode.email') }}" id="report"  method="post" name="form" style="text-align:center;">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  class="section1_input" required  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" placeholder="Đại Hiệp vui lòng để lại Email">

        <span class="section1_message"style="display:block" id="result"> Vui lòng đăng ký = email của bạn để chúng tôi có thể gửi quà về</span>

        <button class="btn btn-outline section1_button" id="submit_form" type ="button" name="submit">
            <img class="" src="{{asset('images/ohdaihiepLandingPage/form/form_button.png')}}" style="width:100%;" alt="">
        </button>
    </form>
```

And my JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#report').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var url = e.target.action
        var formData = $(this).serialize()
        $.post(url, formData, function (response) {
            $('.section1_input').val('');
            var $res=response.message;
            $('#result').text($res);
        });
        $(".section1_message").empty()
    })
})
```

Comment: are you sure page refresh ? because you have use `type="button"`  .

Comment: if I use click , after click I get empty page with customise message {} Maybe I mistake with return view my page and if in this way I use "enter" I same get message {message:  customise text}

Comment: Your submit handler will get called when `type="submit"` so change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and try again .

Comment: Make it your answer. Thank u so much! I change type on type="submit" it is still work correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button type from `button`  to `submit`. It should work fine or else change your event trigger to `click`.

[check this for more detail](https://api.jquery.com/on/)